# Sizing a child element relative to parent's border-box

Tags: sizing, css

If I set the size of a child element in percentage, the size will be calculated relative to parent's [**content-box**](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp), independently from the fact that I have set its `box-sizing` property to `border-box`.

So if I have something like this:

```
.parent {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0 100px;
  width: 600px;
}

.child {
  width: 50%;
}
```

The width of `.child` will be 50% of `400px` (parent's width after padding has been applied). You can see an example here: [**JSBin**](http://jsbin.com/oxUyuxI/2/edit)

#### Main Question

> Is there a way to make the width of a child element relative to the
>   parent's `border-box` rather than the parent's `content-box`?

#### Bonus question

While making my example I noticed a weird behavior in the calculation of the size. Setting the `.parent`'s padding as `0 10%` actually gives a padding of 68-odd pixels from each side. Why is that? Isn't 10% of 600px 60px or I am missing something?

Comment: Could you please post HTML code? Or else update it on jsfiddle

Comment: You find it inside the example link. It is nothing special: just two nested elements, nothing else.

Comment: I wish there was an easy way to do this.

Answer (score 6):

The `width` property is explicitly defined as being relative to the content box and `box-sizing` on the parent doesn't alter this however there is a trick available. What you need is a border that ***doesn't consume any space*** and thankfully that is exactly what the `outline` property does.

There is one catch: The outline defaults to being outside the content box. Not to worry though because one of `outline`'s related properties `outline-offset` accepts negative values which will bring our outline inside our content box!

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <div class="outer">
      <div class="inner">
      TEST
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.outer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  outline:20px solid red;
  border:1px solid black;
  outline-offset: -20px;
}

.inner {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  outline:1px solid yellow;
  position: absolute; /* required so inner is drawn _above_ the outer outline */
  background-color: blue;
}
```

JS Bin: http://jsbin.com/efUBOsU/1/

With regards to your "bonus question" percentage widths are based on the **container size, not the element size**. This is true for `width`, `padding` and `margin`. You're getting a padding of 68px because the container is is 680px. This may seem odd but it comes in very handy when you have a rule like `{width: 80%; padding: 10%;}` because it guarantees your total object dimensions will be 100% of the container and not some arbitrary value based on your child elements' content.

Note: In future please ask additional questions seperately, especially when they are only marginally related to your primary question.

Comment: ```outline``` doesn't allow some sort of ```border-radius```, I think shadow too.