# Fill parent element's size, including its (rounded) border in CSS

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to set the size of a child element such that it fills its parent **and** its parent's (rounded) border? Assuming I cannot simply hardcode everything.

This was my initial code: **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1p9sqLr7/3/)**. The size of the `<a>` is 80 x 80 pixels vs. 82 x 82 pixels for `<li>`, because of its border. The difference is noticeable when activating the `:hover`.

[It seems that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18778527/sizing-a-child-element-relative-to-parents-border-box) using `outline` in place of `border` would do what I want, but there is no cross-browser `outline-radius`. That led me to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5394116/outline-radius) using `box-shadow`; this works ([**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/1p9sqLr7/4/)), but is there a less 'hacky' approach? Semantically, I want a border, not a shadow.

Comment: But that shadow seems like a border. I would have definitely gone with that solution.

Comment: Actually, I am currently using that solution; it just seemed like there must be a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest approach... box-sizing.

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

If you don't want to use that, then the only other logical solution is using box-shadow.

Comment: Looks like this also works if I only add it to `.exp { ... }`. Does it need to be applied to all elements?

Comment: No... you can add it wherever needed or wanted.  Though its a lot easier coding when applied to all elements.  Keeps the code consistent in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

`box-shadow` is probably the most reliable option for cross-browser support, though it's not supported in some older browsers. [Setting the shadow](http://jsfiddle.net/1p9sqLr7/12/) to `inset` has it behave like a border that's inside the element rather than outside, which will should resolve the somewhat 'hacky' look and keep a consistent size.

The way browsers render borders is similar to `margin` or `padding`, which can affect the amount of space an element occupies. Using something that's `inset` (ie, rendered inside an element) avoids this problem.

This approach can be somewhat justified semantically by considering `box-shadow` shorthand for a border with built in gradient functionality and some new options (like 2D `inset` positioning).